# Java Record with @Builder.Default

Tags: java, lombok

I'm wondering is there any way to combine java record with lombok's `@Builder.Default`?
Let's consider an example with properties object for new file creation.

Before java 14

```
@Value
@Builder
public class FileProperties {
    @Builder.Default
    String directory = System.getProperty("user.home");
    @Builder.Default
    String name = "New file";
    @Builder.Default
    String extension = ".txt";
}
```

Java 14

```
@Builder
public record FileProperties (
        String directory,
        String name,
        String extension
) {}
```

But in case if I try to use something like

```
@Builder
public record FileProperties (
        @Builder.Default
        String directory = System.getProperty("user.home")
) {}
```

Compiler will fail with an error, revealing that such syntax is not allowed. Do we have any solution to this problem?

Comment: Not right now, I hadn't considered that when extending support of `@Builder` to records. Unfortunately, I cannot think off of the top of my head of some simple solution to this problem - you can't stick arbitrary expressions in annotations, so e.g. `@Builder.Default(System.getProperty("user.home"))` doesn't compile - lombok can't do it that way.

Comment: Agree. Maybe solution like [mapstruct deals with expressions](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#expressions) will be a good fit. But having expression language support only for @Builder.Default it's a high price

Comment: I hate what mapstruct does. Shove java code in string literals is nuts. No auto-complete. Error checking it is difficult. Syntax colouring is a disaster. Nah, if we do this, probably make you write a static method that produces the value and takes no args, and annotate it with something. For example `@Builder.Default`, and the name has to be defaultX; if it isn't in that format, you get an error on the annotation explaining how to name them.

Comment: Agree, solution with static methods sounds much better. It's even better, then putting this methods inside builder itself. Like here `record FileProperties(@Builder.Default String directory) { class FilePropertiesBuilder {String defaultDirectory(){}} }`. Also, if possible, overriding default method name will be a good idea. Like here `@Builder.Default(method="userHome")`. Such code reusable and much readable.

Comment: It looks like an issue has finally been raised against Lombok for this: [lombok#3547](https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/3547)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can achieve the same outcome not by `@Builder.Default` but by defining the builder itself with defaults for Lombok:

```java
@Builder
public record FileProperties (
        String directory,
        String name,
        String extension
) {
    public static class FilePropertiesBuilder {
        private String directory = System.getProperty("user.home");
        private String name = "New file";
        private String extension = ".txt";
    }
}
```

Then to test it:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(FileProperties.builder().build());
}
```

Output:

```
FileProperties[directory=/home/me, name=New file, extension=.txt]
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use recorde if you want to do more things than recording values in a container. In this case you shouldn't use recorde because it doesn't allowed you to instruct something difference then simple recording your arguments.

If you want a default value for any instance you are creating of this class you need a "normal" constructor.

That's why you can't set values (again) in records.

Comment: I don't think that this argument holds in this case.  The author is (presumably) using the records as a simple container object.  It's just that they're using Lombok's [builder](https://projectlombok.org/features/Builder) functionality to have an API which creates it with default values if unspecified, rather than using the record constructor directly.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is not available at the moment. Per the first comment under the question by Lombok author Reinier Zwitserloot:

> Not right now, I hadn't considered that when extending support of `@Builder` to records.

Reinier goes on to explain why this would be problematic to implement in Lombok:

> Unfortunately, I cannot think off of the top of my head of some simple solution to this problem - you can't stick arbitrary expressions in annotations, so e.g. `@Builder.Default(System.getProperty("user.home"))` doesn't compile - lombok can't do it that way.